# List Inside IQueryable Object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list, iqueryable

Given the following:

```
public class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public IQueryable<Pet> Pets { get;set; }
}

public class Pet
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public int OwnerId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SearchCriteria
{
  public string PersonName {get; set; }
  public List<string> PetNames {get; set;}
}
```

Implementing a select of all Persons with their pets while searching with an IQueryable

```
public List<Person> GetWithPets(SearchCriteria search)
{
     var people = (from p in context.People
                   where p.Name == search.PersonName
                   select new Person{
                          ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Pets = (from pt in context.Pets
                                where pt.OwnerId == p.ID
                                select new Pet {
                                   id = pt.ID,
                                 OwnerId = pt.OwnerId,
                                 Name = pt.Name
                                }).AsQueryable
                   }).AsQueryable();

       foreach(var str in search.PetNames)
       {
            people = people.Where(o=>o.Pets.Any(p=>p.Name == str));
       }
  return people.ToList();
}
```

My problem is that regardless of the foreach that searches the name, in the list of people that returns, pets is null even though there are
pets associated with that person, where did I go wrong ?

**EDIT:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Animal> Pets { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SearchCriteria
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public List<string> PetNames { get; set; }
}



class Program
{
    public static List<Person> GetWithPets(SearchCriteria search)
    {
        using (DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var people = (from p in context.Peoples
                          where p.Name == search.PersonName
                          select new Person
                          {
                              ID = p.ID,
                              Name = p.Name,
                              Pets = (from pt in context.Pets
                                      where pt.OwnerID == p.ID
                                      select new Animal
                                      {
                                          id = pt.ID,
                                          OwnerId = pt.OwnerID,
                                          Name = pt.Name
                                      }).AsQueryable()
                          }).AsQueryable();

            foreach (var str in search.PetNames)
            {
                people = people.Where(o => o.Pets.Any(p => p.Name == str));
            }
            return people.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your method supposed to return? A list of People with `Name` equal to `search.PersonName` and with any pet that has a name that is in `search.PetNames`?

Comment: my method is supposed to return a list of people that have name equals search.PersonName & ALL their pets but only those people who own the pets with those names in the search.PetNames

Comment: Are `Person` and `Pet` entities mapped to DB or are they only helper classes to get the result of the search? What happens if you remove the `foreach` loop? Is `Pets` still `null`?

Comment: No, Person and Pet are just classes I created, they map to People and Pets in entities, If I remove the foreach Pets is still null..

Comment: Is `List<Pet> Pets` really private? I don't know how you could set a private property in your select projection. Also, the result of the inner `from...` is `IQueryable<Pet>`, how can you assign it to a `List<Pet>`, you should get a compiler error.

Comment: @Saluma He should have got a compile time error for `people.Where(o=>o.Pets.Any(p=>p == str));` as `p` is of type `Pet` and `str` is a `string` ! I guess its only a psuedo code

Comment: @Flowerking: Yes, this too! Question must be really fixed to real (compilable) code, otherwise there won't be a useful answer.

Comment: @Slauma I wrote it directly in the editor not in visual studio, didn't check syntax, anyway, I Edited the question...

Comment: @RamiSakr: It still cannot compile because the inner `from...` returns `IQueryable<Pet>` and you cannot assign this to a `List<Pet>` (as already said above). And this fragment is the most important part of your question, it should be *exactly* your real code.

Comment: @Slauma please check the edited question again ... I re-edited the question and converted my list to IQueryable.

Comment: Your code is very confusing: `Pets` really can't be `null` if it's an `IQueryable`. The result might be an empty collection, but not `null`. Can you carefully check if this is the *real* code you are using? Somehow after all the edits I still distrust your code.

Answer (score 2):

*If* `Person` and `Pet` are entities of your model and *if* `Person.Pets` is a navigation property to the `Pet` entity and *if* you want to have the full `Person` entity with all the full `Pet` entities and refering to your comment...

> my method is supposed to return a list of people that have name equals
>   search.PersonName & ALL their pets but only those people who own the
>   pets with those names in the search.PetNames

...you could use this:

```
public List<Person> GetWithPets(SearchCriteria search)
{
    var people = from p in context.People.Include("Pets")
                 where p.Name == search.PersonName
                    && p.Pets.Any(pt => search.PetNames.Contains(pt.Name))
                 select p;

    return people.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you could try something like this

```
var people = (from p in context.People
                   where p.Name == search.PersonName
                   select new Person{
                          ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Pets = (from pt in context.Pets
                                where pt.OwnerId == p.ID
                                select new Pet {
                                   id = pt.ID,
                                 OwnerId = pt.OwnerId,
                                 Name = pt.Name
                                })
                   }).Include("Pets").AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try something like this

```
foreach(var str in search.PetNames)
       {
            people.Concat(people.Where(o=>o.Pets.Any(p=>p == str)).Include('Pet'));
       }
```

Comment: @Jayanga You should edit your other answer, instead of adding another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `AsQueryable()` to `Pets` collection:

```
Pets = (from pt in context.Pets  
        where pt.OwnerId == p.ID  
        select new Pet {  
            id = pt.ID,  
            OwnerId = pt.OwnerId,  
            Name = pt.Name  
        }).AsQuerable()
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried it, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Pet>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Pet>'

Which is in my 
    public class Person
    {
     public int ID { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
     List<Pet> Pets { get;set; }
    }

Comment: @RamiSakr, looking at the error message I suggest replacing `AsQuerable()` on `Pets` with `ToList()` `Pets = (from pt in context.Pets   
        where pt.OwnerId == p.ID   
        select new Pet {   
            id = pt.ID,   
            OwnerId = pt.OwnerId,   
            Name = pt.Name   
        }).ToList()`